# Android Fragment Viewpager blinks/flickers when loading the fragments

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using a viewpager to swipe between Fragments. However, the fragments blink/flash whenver I am loading the first fragment or any newly loaded fragment. any ideas ? I tried the `HardwareAcceleration` disable but nothing.

Comment: Do your fragments do some cpu intensive tasks like loading images, populating a listview, etc.? If yes try using AsyncTask Handlers for them.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel, No, not really.. max allocated memory is around 15MB. CPU is almost not affected..